# braintree payment_method_nonce for embedded device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, braintree

I am trying to use braintree to allow customer pay through a device other than mobile phone or browser. So I can't use braintree client javascript or mobile app sdk.   I want to ask customer to input
their credit card in the device and save it to braintree vault. I can get credit_token and customer_id. 
However to make a payment, latest braintree api need to use payment_method_nonce, which is suppose
to be generated by the web or mobile client SDK. In my case, I can't use the clien SDK. Does anyone
how to generate the payment_method_nonce required without using javascript or mobile sdk. 
Asked braintree support and they said they don't support devices other than browser and mobile phone as 
client.

I used old braintree api, which can use credit_token as payment_method_nonce to make payment. The downside is the credit_card_token is not one time use. Someone may reuse it if they get it.

Comment: I work at Braintree. A credit card token or customer ID should never be returned from you to the device -- your server side library needs to be running on your server, not on the device. That's why a payment method nonce is one time use, because it's returned to the client side.

Comment: One way many people solve this problem in general is by embedding a webview into their application, and using javascript.